# Default reference argument in C++

Tags: c++, class, reference

I have class `mizer`:

```
class mizer {
  ...
  public:
    ...
    void getDeviation( vector<double>&, vector<int>& )
...
};
```

with realization:

```
void mizer::getDeviation( vector<double>& best_mass, vector<int>& best_comb ){
   ...
}
```

But sometimes I do not want to provide the second argument `best_comb`. So I want to set default or something:

```
void mizer::getDeviation( ..., vector<int>& best_comb = default )
```

I tried:

```
static vector<int> def();
...
void mizer::getDeviation( ..., vector<int>& best_comb = def )
```

But it is not working:

```
/minimizer/mizer.C:69:69: error: 
non-const lvalue reference to   type 'vector<int>'  cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'vector<int> ()'double mizer::getDeviation( vector<double>&  best_mass, vector<int>& best_comb=def ){
```

How to set default `vector` reference variable?

Comment: In `static vector<int> def();` `def` is a function, not a vector. See "most vexing parse".

Comment: @nwp It's not really related to the most vexing parse, since that syntax (with parentheses) can *only* be used to declare member functions, not member variables.

Comment: @nwp. Thank you. Sorry for my stupidity. I knew it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static vector<int> def();` declares a static function `def` that returns a `vector<int>`. use `static vector<int> def{};`  or `static vector<int> def;` instead

Answer (score 1):

How about function *overloading*?

You could make an overloaded function taking only one argument, and then use an empty dummy vector to call the two-argument function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method overload, like @Someprogrammerdude suggested:

```
class mizer {
  ...
  public:
    ...
    void getDeviation( vector<double>& );
    void getDeviation( vector<double>&, vector<int>& );
    ...
};

void mizer::getDeviation( vector<double>& best_mass )
{
   vector<int> ignored; 
   getDeviation( best_mass, ignored );
}

void mizer::getDeviation( vector<double>& best_mass, vector<int>& best_comb )
{
   ...
}
```

```
mizer m;
vector<double> mass;
m.getDeviation( mass );
```

```
mizer m;
vector<double> mass;
vector<int> comb;
m.getDeviation( mass, comb );
```

But that is still going to allocate memory for the content of `best_comb` even if the caller does not want it.

Alternatively, you can make the optional parameter be a pointer instead of a reference:

```
class mizer {
  ...
  public:
    ...
    void getDeviation( vector<double>&, vector<int>* = nullptr );
    ...
};

void mizer::getDeviation( vector<double>& best_mass, vector<int>* best_comb )
{
   ...
   if (best_comb) best_comb->push_back(...);
   ...
}
```

```
mizer m;
vector<double> mass;
m.getDeviation( mass );
```

```
mizer m;
vector<double> mass;
vector<int> comb;
m.getDeviation( mass, &comb );
```

Now no memory is allocated for the content of `best_comb` unless the caller wants it.

Answer (score -1):

Your function def() might return always same value.

So, I think you need to use "#define" as default & reference vector.

Comment: I first thought like "Some programmer dude" but, you asked vector reference value ?